# Upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 caused a lot of mouse issues

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.04, synaptics, libinput

- Mouse settings now only has three settings (primary button, double-click, and pointer speed).
- Scrolling has no momentum now. It only scrolls while your fingers are on the touchpad. The moment they leave, the scrolling stops, which is not how it should be.
- Mouse movement is very jerky. Going diagonally, for example, has the cursor zigzagging in that direction.

I think all of this is caused by 17.04 switching to Libinput instead of Synaptic. Libinput has a good palm detection, though, so would be nice if these were fixable.

Anyone have any suggestions?